# both Zooming and Panning a Google Line Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

This is a very straight forward question regarding `google.visualization.LineCHart` and the `explorer` option.

### Question

Is there some way to listen to (or setup) an event that fires when the chart has been zoomed in/out?

### Case

I would like to allow my users to use all three of the `options.explorer.actions` following certain rules:

- When the chart is zoomed out, `dragToZoom` is **enabled**
- When the chart is zoomed in, `dragToPan` and `rightClickToReset` are **enabled**

### Final behaviour

So the user can only zoom in once, then he can pan around and reset back.

Once the chart has been zoomed into, I want to swap the `explorer.action` values to change the behaviour of the chart.

## MWE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Google Visualization API Sample</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src='https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={"modules":[{"name":"visualization","version":"1"}]}'></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

var data = {
    "cols": [{"type":"date","role":"domain"},{"type":"number","role":"data"}],
    "rows": [
        [1980,117.0],[1981,137.0],[1982,142.0],[1983,198.0],[1984,336.0],[1985,117.0],[1986,137.0],[1987,142.0],[1988,198.0],[1989,336.0],
        [1990,117.0],[1991,137.0],[1992,142.0],[1993,198.0],[1994,336.0],[1995,117.0],[1996,137.0],[1997,142.0],[1998,198.0],[1999,336.0],
        [2000,117.0],[2001,137.0],[2002,142.0],[2003,198.0],[2004,336.0],[2005,117.0],[2006,137.0],[2007,142.0],[2008,198.0],[2009,336.0],
    ]
};

function drawVisualization() {
    var table = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.rows.forEach(function(v,i,a){a[i][0]=new Date(v[0],0);});
    table.addColumn(data.cols[0]);
    table.addColumn(data.cols[1]);
    table.addRows(data.rows);
    var wrap = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        "chartType": "LineChart",
        "containerId": "visualization",
        "dataTable" : table,
        "options": {
            "title": "Population Density",
            "legend": "none",
            "width" : 1000,
            "height" : 600,
            "explorer" : {
                "actions" : ["dragToZoom","rightClickToReset"],
                "maxZoomIn" : 0.2,
                "maxZoomOut" : 1.0,
                "zoomDelta" : 10,
                "axis" : "horizontal",
                "keepInBounds" : true
            },
            "animation" : {
                "duration" : 1.5,
                "startup" : false,
                "easing" : "linear"
            }
        }
    });
    google.visualization.events.addListener(wrap,'ready',onReady.bind(wrap));
    wrap.draw();

    function onReady () {
        var chart = this.getChart();
        // somehow attach an event that listens to the chart changing the zoom
        // I would know how to do the rest
    }
}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="visualization"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how did you solve it

Comment: I didn't. I ended doing something else completely with `MutationObserver`s. I'll leave the rest to you. I have stopped using google APIs altogether. Sorry I can't help you out more